# AngularJs net::ERR_ABORTED 404 on github pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, github-pages

I'm working on a project and need to submit through github pages, however, when I upload my project, some of my JS files doesn't load and consoles an error message of Get net::ERR_ABORTED 404.

I have my JS linked `<script src="src/menuList/CategoriesController.js"</script>`
and this is the masseg
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unMSf.png)

and this is my repositories link [enter link description here](https://github.com/Rashad-Harun/Module_4_solution)

and this link is the page it self [enter link description here](https://rashad-harun.github.io/Module_4_solution/#!/)

if someone can help I will be more than thankful
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually happens when you have uppercase directories. For example take the current link for itemsController.js which is https://rashad-harun.github.io/Module_4_solution/src/menulist/itemsController.js, this gives you 404 since the `menuList` directory is referred to as `menulist`. If you change that link to https://rashad-harun.github.io/Module_4_solution/src/menuList/itemsController.js where I just capitalized the `l` letter of the `menulist` word it works.

So my suggestion is to make the sub directory names lowercase. For example:

- Rename the `menuList` directory to `menulist` in your GitHub repo.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate it so much and thank you again for the priceless time that you have spent on solving my problem

Comment: No worries, Rashad!